# not able to update the values of properties of an object in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, object, interface, devtools

I am working on an existing angular project. I have a component in which

```
public testRunDetails: ITestRunDetails[] = [];
```

I have this variable testRunDetails. And  the interface ITestRunDetails is

```
export interface ITestRun {
    ExecutionStartedOn: string;
    ExecutionEndedOn: string;
    ExecutionStatus: string;
    ExecutionResult: string;
    TotalCnt?: number;
    PassedCnt?: number;
    FailedCnt?: number;
    CompletedCnt?: number;
    ...
    ...
}
```

I am trying to change properties of this variable in a function like

```
public changeRunStausRealTime() {
    this.hubConnection.on('transfermessage', (data) => {
      console.log('Message from signalr')

      for (var test of this.testRunDetails) {
        test.ExecutionStatus = "Completed"
        test.ExecutionResult = "Passed"
        test.CurrentStatus = "Test Execution - Pass"
      }
    }
    )
```

Properties `ExecutionStatus` and `ExecutionResult` are defined in ITestRun, but `CurrentStatus` is not. When I try to debug the code, I can see `CurrentStatus` property for the test object
[image]

I am trying to change the value of `ExecutionStatus` , `ExecutionResult` , `CurrentStatus` properties
but only `ExecutionStatus` , `ExecutionResult` are getting changed but not `CurrentStatus`. I am confused about what is happening, why am I not able to update the `CurrentStatus` value?. Why is it appearing the dev tools if that's not a property of `test` object ?

Comment: Where are you creating the object represented by iTestRun?

Comment: instead of using for loop try to use map function of Array.

Answer (score 0):

Try inserting your code inside start()then() and catch()

Comment: which part of code are you referring to? the for loop ?

Comment: Yes I thought you might be using result data for assignment. And the interface name is ITestRun, but you are using ITestRunDetails interface. Also, just check if you are changing the value of this.testRunDetails anywhere outside the method, if so do a deep copy.